# Select first option of select box in in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to select the first option in the select boxes below. I have tried both this.el.selected = true; 
and

```
if (newValue == 0) return "selected";
```

but neither works.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr v-for="result in results">
        <select v-model='products[$index].startTime' class="form-control input">
            <option v-for="(timeIndex, time) in result.start_times" v-selected="timeIndex" >@{{ time.start_time }}-@{{ timeIndex }}</option>
        </select>
    </tr>
</table>

Vue.directive('selected', {
    bind: function () {

    },
    update: function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue==0)
        {
            this.el.selected = true;
        }
        return "";
    },
    unbind: function () {

    }
})
```

How can I go about doing this? What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

Comment: You can just do :selected="$index === 0" in your v-for loop, you don't need a directive

Answer (score 2):

If your select is bound to your v-model, you don't need to select any particular option, Vue knows to bind the value of the keypath specified in v-model to the VALUE you pass the option in the select.

```
<option v-for="(timeIndex, time) in result.start_times" :value="timeIndex" >@{{ time.start_time }}-@{{ timeIndex }}</option>
```

http://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Select-Options

However, you aren't setting a value. Your are binding v-selected="timeIndex". I hadn't ever seen v-selected before, so I looked for it in VueJS docs, it doesn't appear so unless its a custom directive, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: His code shows that he is creating a custom directive

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can bind the selected property to an expression. If the index is 0 then true else false

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr v-for="result in results">
        <select v-model='products[$index].startTime' class="form-control input">
            <option v-for="(timeIndex, time) in result.start_times" :selected="timeIndex === 0" >@{{ time.start_time }}-@{{ timeIndex }}</option>
        </select>
    </tr>
</table>
```